# Hide DIVs in jquery function instead of header redirect

Tags: jquery, function, hide

I have the following `jQuery` function:

```
$("#member-allready").click(function(){
  SetCookie("subscribed","1");
  header("Location: http://www.google.co.uk/");
  return false;
});
```

Instead of the header redirect `header("Location: http://www.google.co.uk/");`
I'd like to hide some divs instead.
e.g `#div1, #div2, #div3 {display: none;}`

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this a PHP question or a jQuery question?

Comment: isn't `header("Location: http://www.google.co.uk/");` is for redirecting in PHP?

Comment: I guess both, php and jquery.
Yes header is to redirect, but wanted to change this to hiding divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [this](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)  in jquery

```
   $("#member-allready").click(function(){
            SetCookie("subscribed","1");    
            $('#div1').hide();
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hide with jquery

```
$("#div1").hide()
```